# How can I fill my combobox with .txt files, but only their name without the path?

Tags: c#, file, combobox

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    cboLanden.Items.Add(file);
}
```

This is my code and it returns the full path, I would like to have only the name, without the path in my combobox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Path.GetFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get file name without path:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; 
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt"); 
foreach (string file in filePaths) 
{ 
   cboLanden.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file)); 
}
```

Also consider to use files as data source of your comboBox:

```
 cboLanden.DataSource = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt")
                                 .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Error 1 'Path' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.IO.Path' and 'System.Windows.Shapes.Path'

Error on Path.GetFileName ? I've added the using.windows.shape and still this?

Comment: @user3173605 use fully qualified name like `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()`

Comment: Thanks for you're answer!

Answer (score 0):

Simple just use this

```
foreach (string file in files) 
{ 
  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
}
```

If there is a file name in files like `c:\coolpic.jpg`
it will return only `coolpic` without extension